# How to store Image in mongodb database collection of a personal details

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, collections, mongoose-schema

**How to store image in mongo db database** I've already created a collection for my user which is including all the personal details of that person. Now I want to add images to it whenever the user uploads. I,ve uploaded image to mongo db using grid fs. But it is in different collection and how to add that image link into the user collection
[This is my user collection there is a field "profilePicId" which i created to access the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvNM7.jpg)

[This is my image collection. whenever a user uploads an image it'll be sent to uploads. I connect this two collection with the id. Is there any other way to connect ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RraJb.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you read [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/150669/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-store-large-files-10-mb-in-a-database) first. The way you are saving your images is not wrong at all but i could say there's a best approach for that, what i mean is about cloud services to store files, my favorite one is the [aws s3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/?nc1=h_ls), you have a free tier to make tests and it's very simple to create an account and setup the bucket.

Doing so, you can upload the files from nodejs with [multer-s3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/getting-started-nodejs.html) or with the [aws-sdk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/getting-started-nodejs.html) and then just store the link for the file in your database.

Using a proper service to store files you can take out a lot of weight from your database and just keep the necessary data for your app.

But if you want keep doing the way you are doing now, on your member schema you have to create a new field that refers to an id of the collection uploads and later you use the [population](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#population) method to access the related objects from a query. As you didn't provide any code i will leave an example from mongoose docs:

#### Implementing the reference to another schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const personSchema = Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: String,
  age: Number,
  // Here we store an array of id from schema story, so a person
 // can have many stories
  stories: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});

const storySchema = Schema({
  // the author field stores just one person id, so every story
  // has one author
  author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' },
  title: String,

  // but one story can have many fans, so it's refers to
 // an array of person id
  fans: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' }]
});

const Story = mongoose.model('Story', storySchema);
const Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
```

#### saving a new author

```
const author = new Person({
  _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
  name: 'Ian Fleming',
  age: 50
});

author.save(function (err) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  // Here we are creating a new story and assigning the author id
  // to field author, that way we can populate it later.
  const story1 = new Story({
    title: 'Casino Royale',
    author: author._id    // assign the _id from the person
  });

  story1.save(function (err) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    // that's it!
  });
});
```

#### Querying with populate

```
Story.
  findOne({ title: 'Casino Royale' }).
  // Populate returns the author field as 
 // an object containing all data from the id
// assigned here earlier
  populate('author').
  exec(function (err, story) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    console.log(story.author);
      //  { 
     //     _id: 4edd40c86762e0fb12000003
    //      name: Ian Fleming
   //       age: 50
  //      }
  });
```

Hope i clarified the things a bit, make sure you read the [mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate) as well, almost all you need is there.